# Let $a$ and $b$ be positive real numbers. If $x^2 + y^2 \le1$ then the largest $ax + by$ is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, plane-geometry

The problem: 
[image]

The solution:

[image]

---

-Why is the equation $y=\frac{a}{b}x+\frac{c}{b}$  a *line* if $\frac{c}{b}$ is not constant?  That is, $c$ varies as either $y$ or $x$ varies, but if this equation is a line, then the constant term $\frac{c}{b}$ can't vary, precisely because it's *constant*, which is not possible if $c$ is varying.  Clearly, I'm missing a detail.

-A tangent line to a disc isn't necessary perpendicular to the line segment formed by the center of the disc and the point of interception between the line and the disc.  The tangent line can be tilted up or down (so not perpendicular) and still be ''touching'' the disc, so why in this case this line is necessarily perpendicular?

Comment: You say "A tangent line to a disc isn't necessarily perpendicular to the line segment formed by the center of the disc and the point of interception", but in fact it _is_ necessarily perpendicular. This is in fact one of the ways of defining the circle.

Comment: Any (smooth, non-intersecting) plane curve has exactly one tangent line at any given point along the curve; you can 'tilt' the line, but that changes the point of tangency.

Comment: $ax+yx = c_i$ is an infinite family of of lines all parallel.  The only such lines that can be achieved are those that intersect the circle.  The maximum possible achievable c is for that one line that is tangent.

Comment: "The tangent line can be tilted up or down (so not perpendicular) and still be ''touching'' the disc"  No.  It can not.

Comment: The distance from the center of the circle to the point of the tangent line is equal to the radius.  The distance from the center to any other point is greater than the radius.  So the point of the tangent line is the shortest distance from the center to the tangent line.  The shortest distance has to be perpendicular.  Tangents are always perpendicular to the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Why is the equation y=(a/b)x+c/b a line if c/b is not constant? That is, c varies as either y or x varies*"

$c$ *is* a constant.  The text kind of blew this.  And then the abused this.  Perhaps a clearer way of putting it would be:

Consider a value $c$ and all the $x,y$ such that $ax + by = c$.  These points form a line.  If this line passes through the interior of the disk then $c$  is a possible value for $ax + by$ where $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$. If this line misses the disk altogether then $c$ is not a possible value.

Different values of $c$ will create different lines, all parallel.  larger values of $c$ will be to the "right" of lower values of $c$.  The largest possible value of $c$ which will form the line that intersects the circle at just the furthest most right point that a parallel line with that slope can.

In other words the tangent line.

"*A tangent line to a disc isn't necessary perpendicular to the line segment formed by the center of the disc and the point of interception between the line and the disc.*"

Actually, yes it is.  That *is* a necessary condition.

Consider a line and a point not on the line.  We can construct a line from the point to the line that is perpendicular to that line.  Such a perpendicular is unique and length of this perpendicular is the shortest distance from the point to the line[$*$].

So if the tangent line is *not* perpendicular to the radius, then it is *not* the shortest distance from the center to line.  So there is a point of the tangent line that is a *shorter* distance from the center than the radius.  That would mean the tangent line passes through the *interior* of the circle and the tangent line is a chord.  Presumably that is impossible as chords intersect a circle twice and tangent lines only once.

Furthermore, at a point of a circle we can create a line perpendicular to the radius.  The radius will be the shortest distance from the center to the line so all other points of the line are further away from the center than the radius.  Hence this line intersects the circle at only that on point.

So if tangent means "line that intersects the circle at exactly one point" then that line is precisely the perpendicular to the radius and no other such line exists.

If tangent means "line that intersects at a point and has the same slope of curve" then we have to prove that chords that intersect the circle at two points can not be tangent.  That's intuitively obvious but I think we need calculus concepts to prove it.

[$*$] This is basically Euclid's fifth postulate consequences.  A parallel line exists through the point, $p$, and a unique perpendicular exists at that point.  The perpendicular crosses the original parallel line at a perpendicular as well at point $q$.  If we take any other point, $s$ on the line we will have a right triangle $pqs$ and the hypotenuse $ps$ will be longer than the base $pq$.  So $q$ is the unique point on the line that is closest to $p$.

Comment: Great.  Now, it looks so obvious that I'm angry at myself for not understanding this.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, observe the following popular inequality: $(ax+by)^2 \le (a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)\le a^2+b^2 \implies |ax+by| \le \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\implies ax+by \le \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, and this is the maximum that you sought.

Comment: And the name of this is Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality

Comment: This is a brilliant way of solving this problem.  I find it much more understandable.  I wonder why this wasn't used instead.

Comment: @StephenSafee The reason this wasnt used is that proofs using Cauchy-Schwarz tend to be more non-intuitive while here we have a direct geometrical interpretation. We prefer always to gain insights from the geometrical interpretations and then only move on to other methods.

Answer (score 1):

The line $ax+by=c$ is the locus of points in the plane where the function $f(x,y)=ax+by$ attains the value $c$. Varying $c$, we have a family of parallel lines. We are looking for the largest $c$ such that the line $ax+by=c$ intersects the disc $x^2+y^2\leq 1$.

Comment: Ah, so,  $c=f(x,y)= ax+by$ is not a line but a *plane*, $ $ and $ax+by=C$  (where $C$ is the maximum value we seek) is a line in this plane.  Right?

Comment: If you prefer a 3D interpretation then  $z=ax+by$ is a plane and $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ is a  infinite vertical solid cylinder in  $\mathbb{R^3}$. The intersection plane-cylinder is an ellipse. You are looking for the $z$-coordinate of the highest point of the intersection set.

Comment: However, given $c$, $c=ax+by$ is a LINE in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: $c$ is a constant value.  The question asks what is the highest value.  Let c be that value.  Then c = ax + by is a line.  if the line goes through the disk then c cant be the highest value because all the points in the disk to thee right yield higher values.  If the line misses the disk altogether, then ... it's not an acceptable answer.  So the line must be tangent.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\pars{a \quad b}{x \choose y} \leq \root{a^{2} + b^{2}}\root{x^{2} + y^{2}}
\leq \root{a^{2} + b^{2}}
\end{align}

Comment: You're skipping some major steps though.  Check DeepSea's answer.